# Problems trying to integrate Paypal certificate changes into GoDaddy shared hosting environment

Tags: ssl, paypal

I have zero experience with setting up root and intermediate certificates on web servers. Paypal is implementing security changes for all merchants to use SHA256, TLS1.2 and this specific [Verisign G5 certificate](https://knowledge.symantec.com/support/mpki-for-ssl-support/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=SO5624). They have set up their sandbox with new requirements so we can test our current servers and code to ensure compliance come Sept 2016. I use GoDaddy shared hosting. They have the first two in place but they use their own certificates. Paypal insists merchants must use this particular G5 root certificate and GoDaddy insists that what they have is fine. But can't get them working. All is fine with current environment. I've upgraded to a new CPanel shared hosting account to test if that can be a solution but that is not working with sandbox either. Paypal has sent me two certificates, from what I understand I have to use one for my application code and the other has to be the server root certificate. The root is what I'm having a problem with. Conflicting stances from both Paypal and GoDaddy and with Paypal Merchant Tech Support now not accepting any calls, only tickets that take days to communicate, it will put many merchants in a problem situation. Has anyone got any advice on how these certificates work, how many I actually need and how I can get the root certificate installed on GoDaddy's shared hosting platform?

Answer (score 0):

After much communication and trial and error, it looks like GoDaddy's newer accounts are working fine with Paypal's sandbox. So long as the platform is TLS1.2 with SHA2(256) and there is 2048-bit encryption on their SSL, it seems to work. Paypal's documentation that specifies that the "Verisign 2048 G5 certificate must be used" should say "or equivalent".